# Seeding boost::random_generator with boost_random_device

Tags: c++, boost

I would like to seed the boost::random_generator with a true random number. I know that random device is a non-deterministic random number generator. What would be the best way to do this? Is it even possible? If I can't do it directly can I maybe pass it to a boost::mt19937?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So just to follow up with this. I am pretty sure this is possible. After much research I found that random device is one of the only non-header only libs in random so it will need to be compiled.

However, I didn't end up using random device. Instead I opted for the following method of seeding:

```
randomNumberGenerator.seed(boost::chrono::duration_cast<boost::chrono::nanoseconds>(boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count());
boost::uuids::detail::seed(randomNumberGenerator);
```

Where randomNumberGenerator is of the type boost::mt19937

Hope this helps!!